# How to draw a point grid over a relatively positioned image?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two images of equal dimensions and want to add a point grid over each of them. Then, the corresponding points should be connected by a line. It should more or less look like this (I have only connected the upper and lower row of points.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
    spec/.style={decoration=snake}
]{
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (F) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image.jpg}};
    \node[above right=of F,anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (B) at (1,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(F.south east)},y={(F.north west)}]
        %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {1,...,9} {
            \foreach \y in {1,...,9}{
                \node[draw,circle,fill,blue,inner sep=0.5pt] (F\x\y) at (\x/10,\y/10) {};
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
\begin{scope}[x={(B.south east)},y={(B.north west)}]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,9} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,9}{
      \node[draw,circle,fill,green,inner sep=0.5pt] (B\x\y) at (\x/10,\y/10) {};
      \draw[decoration=snake] (B\x\y)--(F\x\y);
    }
  }
\end{scope}
}
\end{document}
```

The lines seem to be fine, but the green points grid just isn't getting right. What am I missing?

Comment: @CarLaTex Yes they should. The lines are still black, because the actual images are not black. Feel free to change colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layers might be useful here. Also using the implicit `xyz` coordinate system:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(330:1.414cm),y=(90:2cm),z=(210:2cm),line cap=round]
\foreach \layer/\dotcolor [count=\k]  in {background/green, main/blue}{
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{\layer}
  \path [fill=black, fill opacity=0.875]
     (0,0,\k) -- (1,0,\k) -- (1,1,\k) -- (0,1,\k) -- cycle;
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4}\foreach \j in {1,...,4}
    \path [fill=\dotcolor] (\j*.2, \i*.2, \k) circle [radius=.0125]
      coordinate (n-\i-\j-\k);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}\foreach \j in {1,...,4}
  \draw [gray, decoration={snake, amplitude=1}, decorate] 
     (n-\i-\j-1) -- (n-\i-\j-2);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the x- and y-vectors to fit the picture. This works for the first picture, because it is positioned at (0,0). But for the second it doesn't, because it's not positioned at the origin. Drawing the vectors (see commented parts in the code below) reveales this:

[image]

Here your green points are perfectly positioned in a not perfect 1x1 "rectangle".

This can be corrected by subtracting the anchor point of B when setting the vectors xB and yB:

```
x={($(B.south east) - (B.south west)$)},
y={($(B.north west) - (B.south west)$)}
```

Additionally the anchor point has to be added to the positions of the green points to shift them into the second picture:

```
($(\x/10,\y/10) + (B.south west)$)
```

This results in:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[demo,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
    spec/.style={decoration=snake}
]{
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (F) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image.jpg}};
    \node[above right=of F,anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (B) at (1,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(F.south east)},y={(F.north west)}]
        %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {1,...,9} {
            \foreach \y in {1,...,9}{
                \node[draw,circle,fill,blue,inner sep=0.5pt] (F\x\y) at (\x/10,\y/10) {};
            }
        }
        % draw x and y vector
        %\draw[cyan,->] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$xF$};
        %\draw[cyan,->] (0,0) -- (0,1) node[above] {$yF$};
    \end{scope}
\begin{scope}[x={($(B.south east) - (B.south west)$)},y={($(B.north west) - (B.south west)$)}]
%\begin{scope}[x={(B.south east)},y={(B.north west)}]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,9} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,9}{
      \node[draw,circle,fill,green,inner sep=0.5pt] (B\x\y) at ($(\x/10,\y/10) + (B.south west)$) {};
%      \node[draw,circle,fill,green,inner sep=0.5pt] (B\x\y) at (\x/10,\y/10) {};
      \draw[red,decoration=snake] (B\x\y)--(F\x\y);
    }
  }
  % draw x and y vector
  %\draw[cyan,->] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$xB$};
  %\draw[cyan,->] (0,0) -- (0,1) node[above] {$yB$};
  % lines to show the 1x1 rectangle
  %\draw[cyan] (1,0) -- (1,1);
  %\draw[cyan] (0,1) -- (1,1);
\end{scope}
}
\end{document}
```